# Responsive website works fine on Firefox responsive mode, not working on Chrome Mobile or trough broswers like Instagram and Facebook ones

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am using vanila Css and having sucsess on the mobile Firfox broswer but a a problem occuring using Chrome broswer.
Here is the [link](http://riste.cf). 
Man i could not fixed. removing the footer which is fixed only partly solves the problem the right blank white[image: The right banner]

Comment: What is the problem? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Beware: the link is blocked by my isp, might be some malware or scam site

Comment: Do you have white space in the right in mobile view? Is this the problem?

Comment: Man yes how od i remove it, if u swipe right it appears, how to remove that shit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "#footerTxt" element in the "#footer", you may modify it's css. If you remove the 'width' from it, the view is will normalizing (white space will remove from the right side).
You need to change/modify this "#footerTxt width" property.

Comment: Man thank u  your the mann